# Yasnippet not being loaded automatically in php-mode

Tags: yasnippet

I have a list of yasnippets for php mode in `~/.emacs.d/yasnippets/php-mode`. One of the them is var_dump.yasnippet:

```
#name : var_dump
# key: vd
# --
var_dump($0);
```

The weird thing is that it's not being loaded when I open a php file. All the other yasnippets are loaded. I thought, that a compiled version of php-mode yasnippets is used. But I don't have any compiled yasnippet files in php-mode directory. I upgraded yasnippet to the last version from github.

Every time I start Emacs I have to manually navigate to var_dump.yasnippet and load it into the memory.

How to load var_dump yasnippet when php file is loaded?

Comment: Is it possible you have another snippet with `# name: var_dump`?

Comment: @npostavs Yes, I thought about that, but snippets must be independent for each mode, and I don't have any more var_dumps inside php-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was another snippet having the same name:

```
#name : var_dump
# key: getdefinedvars
# --
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```